# problem reading hex values from file with NSString or NSData

Tags: iphone, nsdata

I have a file which I need to grab some data from but I am only getting nil when i read it.

the file contains

```
K vU™"3Dô 
U0?*
```

the hex values are

```
1B 1B 01 1B 4B 07 20 1B 76 02 06 55 AA 11 22 33 44 99 20 0A 1B 55 30 1B 1B 3F 0C 1B 2A 01 0C 0C
```

I have tried reading the file a few ways but always get nil when i turn it into a string.

```
NSData *textData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];

NSLog(@"%@",[textData description]);
//prints out <1b1b011b 4b07201b 76020655 aa112233 4499200a 1b55301b 1b3f0c1b 2a010c0c>

text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:textData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//at this point text is nil

text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:err];
//at this point text is still nil

text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:err];
//at this point text is still nil
```

I know its reading the file. I can print out the attributes and see it says the size is 30. what did i miss/what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is probably simply not encoded in UTF8. That's why trying to interpret the data into some UTF8 string fails.

Are you sure it is not UTF-16 (LE or BE) or any other encoding? (or maybe simply ASCII -- with some non-printable characters)

Comment: im guessing it has something to do with either the size, or some of the characters. I have a few files that I have to read from and this is the only one that causes an issue so far but I cannot see what the problem is. I guess I will just have to go through and see which character it hates to have a better idea

Comment: It seems that the text in the file contains **a lot** of control characters, that's probably what messes things up with the decoding process. See [here](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder?encoding=hex&bytes=1B1B011B4B07201B76020655AA1122334499200A1B55301B1B3F0C1B2A010C0C) (from [this site](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder)) for the detail of the interpretation of your hex bytes in UTF8.

Comment: looks like in this case it is the AA and 99 characters. hmm. thanks for that site!

Comment: You're welcome, I just discovered it myself too by googling "utf8 decode" before answering your comment ^^

Answer (score -1):

How about `text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[textData description]];`? :)

Comment: this doesn't seem to get interpreted as the data, but rather turns the hex value into the character value. in other words, instead of the character '0x1b' it prints 1b as 2 characters.